# Why does my custom Binomial Function give me an $Inf$ in return?

Tags: r

So for the statistical computing class I'm in, one of the questions from a recent lecture featured this code:

```
nchoosek = 1 #initialize at 1 
n = 200
k = 100

for (i in 1:(n-k)){
    nchoosek = nchoosek*(k+i)/i }
    
nchoosek
```

The reason I'm posting is I was just playing around with this little bit of code and when n = k it will give you Inf in return. Why am I getting this value? Thanks.

Comment: well, `(n-k)` is zero so you are looping with `i` from `1:0` which does 1 first, then 0. Then you try to divide by `i` which is 0 which is where the infinity comes from.  You can't divide by 0.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks! I see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `n == k` the for loop runs through the values `1:0` which is `c(1,0)` which is not what you want. Put in an `if` statement which skips the for loop if `k>=n` and it should work.

Comment: Jus wanted to provide an update: added an if and else statement and things work as intended now :)

Comment: Cool. It's an easy mistake to make as in other languages the equivalent for loop would just not run, rather than count backwards.

Comment: @pseudospin This is why you should use `seq_len(n)` instead if `1:n`.